# How to assign relationship to-many relationship object back to entity?

Tags: swift, core-data

How can i assign relationship objects **[which having to-many relationship to entity]** back to entity after modifying or adding new object in relations objects?. Right now what i'm actually doing is after getting all relationship objects i'm assigning it to **selectedQA** array  and after modifying or adding new object in this **selectedQA** i'm reassigning it back to entity. I'm not sure this is right way or not. Please help me with this.

```
 var selectedQA = [SurveyQA]() //Temporary array
 var survey:SurveyList //Main Entity Object
```

Getting objects from relationship and asssigning to temp Object

```
    if let surveyQAs = survey.surveyQARelation?.allObjects as? [SurveyQA] {
       selectedQA = surveyQAs
   }
```

For saving back to Relationship objects

```
    survey.surveyQARelation = NSSet(array: selectedQA)

    try! coreDataManager.managedContext.save()
```

[image: Survey][image: SurveyQA]

Comment: Without seeing your schema, it is not easy to answer this question.

Comment: i added schema screenshot @GregoryHigle

Comment: You have a standard bidirectional relationship. You only need to assign one side of it and Core Data will take care of the other side for you _automatically_.

Comment: A quick comment on naming. It's best not to use the word `Relation` to name your relationships. A relationship just indicates an attribute (or collection) of a certain kind. So a SurveyQA has a `survey`, not a `surveyRelation`. I would find the name `surveyRelation` odd and confusing. Similarly, your `surveyQARelation` should just be called `surveyQAs`. If you were building a data model that was not in Core Data, you would not use the word `Relation` to describe related entities, would you? If so, you should not do it in Core Data either.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will change it and keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Core Data documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html):

> When you need to change a relationship, Core Data takes care of the object graph consistency maintenance for you, so you need to change only one end of a relationship. This feature applies to to-one, to-many, and many-to-many relationships.

In other words, for any bidirectional relationship, it is enough to change only *one side* of the relationship. Core Data will take care of updating the other side.

Comment: I understand the meaning but practically how should i assign it back to entity?

Comment: Apple is telling you that _you don't need to_. They will do it for you.

Comment: So the way right now i'm assigning object back is right. Right?

Comment: It's fine. I believe the recommendation is to assign the to-one side of the relationship rather than the to-many side because it is easier, but either one will do.

Comment: Thanks For answer